# ¿Cómo cargar más de una imágen en un mismo registro de Mysql usando PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, php7

Estoy trabajando con un formulario en PHP que inserta registros a Mysql de tipo texto y números, entre ellos inserta una imagen la cual se almacena en una carpeta y después guardo la ruta dentro de un campo en mi BDD, esto con la intención de poderlos visualizar en una tabla en mi contenido web y poder agregarles botones de eliminar y modificar.
Mi duda es **cómo poder agregar más de una imagen por registro???** y poder modificar mi ruta en mi BDD quisiera agregar un botón sobre el registro que me envíe a mi catálogo de imágenes de este registro. Les dejo el código que actualmente esta funcionando.

formulario.php

```
<form action="registro.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="archivo">Ingresar imágenes</label>
  <input type="file" class="form-control-file" accept="image/*" id="archivo" 
  name="archivo" required>

  <label for="nombre">Nombre(s):</label>       
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre(s)" 
  id="nombre" name="nombre" required>

  <label for="apellido_P">Apellido Paterno:</label> 
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido Paterno" 
  id="apellido_P" name="apellido_P" required>

  <label for="apellido_M">Apellido Materno:</label> 
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido Materno" 
   id="apellido_M" name="apellido_M" required>

  <button type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

registro.php

```
 <?php
  require 'conexion.php';
  $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
  $apellido_P = $_POST['apellido_P'];
  $apellido_M = $_POST['apellido_M'];

  //Recogiendo la imágen y generando la ruta destino.
  if(isset($_FILES['archivo'])){
    $nombreImg=$_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    $ruta=$_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
    $destino="imagenes/".$nombreImg;
    if(copy($ruta,$destino)){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO registros (nombre, ruta, 
    apellido_paterno, apellido_materno) VALUES ('$nombre', '$destino', 
    '$apellido_P', '$apellido_M')";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $id_insert = $mysqli->insert_id;

    if($resultado){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Agregado Correctamente"); 
    window.location="formulario.php";</script>';

    }else{
    die("Error".mysqli_error($mysqli));
      }
     }
    }
   ?>
```

index.php (Dónde visualizo mis datos de mysql y la imagen cargada)

```
 <html>
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>ID</th>
       <th>Imágen</th>
       <th>Nombre</th>
       <th>Apellido_P</th>
       <th>Apellido_M</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
       <tbody>
         <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
            <td><?php echo $row['id_registro']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo '<img src="'.$row['ruta'].'" width="200px" 
            height="150px">'?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['apellido_paterno']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['apellido_materno']; ?></td>
        </tbody>
  </html>
```

Comment: creando otra tabla llamada imagenes donde tengas el `id_imagen`,`nombre_imagen`,`id_usuario` luego de insertar el nombre y apellido del usuario solo tomas el `$mysqli->insert_id;` para ingresar las imagenes con `insert into(nombre_imagen,id_usuario) values('$ruta','$id_insert')` a la hora de la query seria poner el `where id_usuario==$id;` si traeras todas la imagenes de ese usuario

Comment: Tienen que estar enlazas amigo @Bryro ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale, te recomiendo que crees una tabla para almacenar exclusivamente las imágenes con una columna que contenga la `id` del usuario al que le pertenezca cada imagen. Luego te traigas de la tabla `imagenes` (por darle un nombre) las fotos según la `id_registro` y las muestres en el `while`